# Get a range("") from a (.find) or (vlookup)

Tags: vba, excel

my question is this:

I've looking for a way to get a range where I got the first result from the `.Find(fecha)`

```
Dim fecha As Date
Dim fechadepo As Date
Dim deposito As Double
fecha = Sheets("Ingresos").range("J4")
fechadepo = Sheets("Datos").range("P7:P1500").Find(fecha)
deposito = fechadepo
```

Ignore the last line, the real thing that a I want to save in this variable (deposito) is the cell next to this one

I would love to save the range where I got the result of use `.Find(fecha)` in order to use `activecell.offset(0.2)` and of that way save information into variables, then those variables save them into a column in another sheet, I've looking hours and hours, it wasn't in vain, i've learning a lot of tips to improve performance coding, avoid use (.select) (.active) (yeah, and I hope to use activecell ...) etc.

How the title says, I tried to use `application.vlookup()`, I get the result too, but I keep without save the result into a range, or save the range where I got the result into a a variable, this is getting me mad!

I really appreciate your help, and good night

Comment: `Sheets("Datos").range("P7:P1500").Find(fecha).offset(0,2)` maybe

Comment: Thanks!! @jsotola this works!! , I tried before, I swear it! but I was using other variables where I got many errors so didn't work that time

Answer (score 0):

You're close. `.Find` returns a `Range` object but you were sticking it straight into a `Date`.  This should work for you:

```
Dim fecha As Date, fechadepo As Date
Dim rge_Find As Range, findAddr As String
fecha = Sheets("Ingresos").Range("J4")
Set rge_Find = Range("P7:P1500").Find(fecha)
fechadepo = rge_Find.Value
findAddr = rge_Find.Address
```

In regards to your comments about `vlookup`, anmd more advanced option is the **Index** / **Match** Combo which provides more functionality than a basic `vlookup`. See [this](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/)  and [this](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/).

Comment: This intrigues me, I'm going to read this, maybe is more efficient than what  I'm triying to do

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("Datos").range("P7:P1500").Find(fecha).offset(0,2)`

This is the correct answer!!

ting ting ting!
 We have a winner!! **thanks to @jsotola**

I'm feeling so silly now ... No problem, I'm very new in this world